# How to disable Toolbar on certain pages / theme?

Tags: 8

Before [deprecation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755) of `hook_page_build/hook_page_build_alter()` we used good old method:

```
$page['page_top']['toolbar']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

([*Source*](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/promokit/tree/themes/promokit_presentation/promokit_presentation.theme?id=a2e66d1b51446314d892b9e242843a1d1ea4e208#n67))

It disabled Toolbar for specific route in specific theme.

Now I checked `hook_page_top()`, `hook_toolbar()` and `hook_preprocess_page()`. Nothing helped, so I temporarily removed `{{ page_top }}` region from my *html.html.twig* but it doesn't look as the right approach.

Comment: May you show the code you tried, so far? I don't understand in which way `hook_page_top()` could not help you. See [`toolbar_page_top()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!toolbar!toolbar.module/function/toolbar_page_top/8) and [`block_page_top()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!block.module/function/block_page_top/8).

Comment: @kiamlaluno `hook_page_top()` is for adding new content to top, not for altering existing one. So, I have to control the weight of my module which again looks odd for such simple task.

Comment: Since the array is passed by reference, you can alter existing array keys it contains too. Since there is not a `hook_page_top_alter()`, nothing forbids you from using that hook.

Comment: There is still hook_module_implements_alter :P

Answer (score 1):

*page_top* and *page_bottom* are still available, but on [html.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!themes!classy!templates!layout!html.html.twig/8). [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8) initializes those variables with the following code.

```
  $variables['page_top'] = NULL;
  if (isset($variables['html']['page_top'])) {
    $variables['page_top'] = $variables['html']['page_top'];
    unset($variables['html']['page_top']);
  }
  $variables['page_bottom'] = NULL;
  if (isset($variables['html']['page_bottom'])) {
    $variables['page_bottom'] = $variables['html']['page_bottom'];
    unset($variables['html']['page_bottom']);
  }
```

Since [`toolbar_page_top()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!toolbar!toolbar.module/function/toolbar_page_top/8) uses the following code, I take you can use `hook_preprocess_html()` to avoid the toolbar appears.

```
  $page_top['toolbar'] = array(
    '#type' => 'toolbar',
    '#access' => \Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access toolbar'),
    '#cache' => [
      'keys' => ['toolbar'],
      'contexts' => ['user.permissions'],
    ],
  );
```

Bear in mind that a note on [Added hook_page_attachments(_alter)() and removed hook_page_build/alter()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755) says:

> You no longer can change $page['content'] (or, generally speaking, $page[$region_name]) into something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is implementing `hook_module_implements_alter()` to remove the implementation of `hook_page_top()` done from the Toolbar module, implement `hook_page_top()` in your module, and call `toolbar_page_top()` when necessary.

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'page_top') {
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    unset($implementations['toolbar']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}

function mymodule_page_top(array &$page_top) {
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
  if ($theme != "theme where you don't want the toolbar" && \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('toolbar')) {
    toolbar_page_top($page_top);
  }
}
```

In the example code I am showing, the toolbar is added only when the current theme is not a specific one.

Comment: although this solution will remove the toolbar content, this is not going to remove classes added by the Toolbar to `body`.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity with Toolbar removal is that not only markup in `page_top` must be removed, but also classes added to the `<body>`.

The code below allows to add `$settings['hide_admin_toolbar'] = TRUE;` to your `settings.local.php` and remove both Toolbar markup and classes.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // Hide admin toolbar.
  if (Settings::get('hide_admin_toolbar')) {
    if (!empty($variables['attributes']['class'])) {
      unset($variables['page_top']['toolbar']);
      $variables['attributes']['class'] = array_filter($variables['attributes']['class'], function ($value) {
        return strpos($value, 'toolbar-') !== 0;
      });
    }
  }
}
```